# mySQL Return field names from multiple foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm new to mySQL and was hoping to get some help. I have a table layed out in the following way:

```
TASK
task_id *
tasktype_id (FK)
proj_id (FK)
empl_id (FK)
taskstat_id (FK)
hrs
notes
```

If I do a query like this, the results print out fine but the numeric references to foreign keys are printed.

```
SELECT * AS task FROM task
INNER JOIN tasktype ON tasktype.tasktype_id = task.tasktype_id
WHERE taskstat_id = 1";
```

But I would like to print out the field names instead of field numbers for the foreign keys in the resulting table. Any ideas? This is what I tried, but without any luck.

```
SELECT task.task_id,
       tasktype.tasktype_id,
       project.proj_id,
       employee.empl_id,
       taskstatus.taskstat_id,
       task.hrs,
       task.note
FROM task, tasktype, project, employee, taskstatus                      
INNER JOIN tasktype ON tasktype.tasktype_id = task.tasktype_id
WHERE task.taskstat_id = 1";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, assuming the "field name" in the related tables (column name) is called... name (I don't know the structure of your joined tables)

```
select t.task_id,
       tt.name, //or tt.description, or whatever
       p.name, //same
       e.name, //same
       ts.name, //same 
       t.hrs,
       t.note
FROM task t
inner join tasktype tt on tt.tasktype_id = t.tasktype_id
inner join project p on p.proj_id = t.proj_id
inner join employee e on e.empl_id = t.empl_id
inner join taskstatus ts on ts.taskstat_id = t.taskstat_id
where t.taskstat_id = 1
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.